# How stl containers destroy objects

Tags: c++, stl

How does stl call the destructors of objects, as in std::vector::erase or std::vector::pop_back?

Comment: Do you mean the semantics (e.g. order), or what C++ syntax they use to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps some additions to Steve's nice answer:

Indeed, internal allocation is done by allocators, which serve two separate purposes: Allocating and releasing memory, and constructing and destroying objects. Objects are always (copy or move) constructed on `insert` and destroyed on `erase`, however, the interna vary.

Node-based containers will typically allocate and construct an entire internal *node*, which contains both the actual object *and* bookkeeping data (like the next/prev pointers in a doubly-linked list). When you erase one of those, the container will destroy the object and release the memory.

Sequence containers like vector will strictly separate allocation and construction; the amount of memory that's been allocated will typically only *grow*, but when you erase (after the erased object's destructor has been called), the other elements have to be moved to maintain contiguous memory layout.

The internal allocator work may look quite different from your usual `new/delete` work if you haven't seen it before, but ultimately there's always a construction and a destruction somewhere.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. Is it something like this?

http://pastebin.com/yyCYCAZB

Only in STL's case those functions are implemented in a class?

Comment: @PiMaster: Yeah, those are the typical workhorse functions of an allocator (but beware, a true allocator class has to satisfy tons of additional requirements).

Comment: Not really a ton of requirements, but one really horrible one about being global for the type, not instance. I should check if C++0x actually fixed this.

Comment: @edA: You also have to define a ton of typedefs and the infamous `rebind` mechanics...

Comment: I looked at my code again, and yeah, I suppose it is a lot: 7 typedefs, 1 silly rebind, 11 functions.

Answer (score 6):

The `vector` has an [allocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6td8khx.aspx) associated with it, the [destroy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83f353w9.aspx) member is used to clean up.

> Calls an objects destructor without deallocating the memory where the
>   object was stored.

Incidentally you can follow this through the source yourself, given decent IDE.